# Add custom implicit object in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Every one knows there are a set of implicit object in JSP like `session`, `request` etc.

Is there a way to add your own custom-implicit object to it so that it will be readily available in all JSPs?

Comment: What would your custom implicit object do that it would be used by all JSPs ?

Comment: If you have to add it, it's not implicit anymore, is it? So add a request or session or application attribute, and you'll have access to this attribute in your JSP.

Comment: This will be used by other members for debug and testing purpose. I want to force a variable name hence the session and request attribute will not work.

Comment: Tell us more precisely what you want to do. Forcing a variable name doesn't mean anything to me.

Comment: I mean as we have request object, we don't have choice of getting this object with other name. Suppose i want object with variable name 'abc' of some type to be available than it should be available as abs.

Comment: `request.setAttribute("abc", someObject)` will add an attribute to the request, that you can use in the JSP using `${abc}`. Isn't it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could set your custom object in request or session and access that in JSP.

Comment: I want to force the variable name which cant be achieved through this.

Comment: You could try to include a JSP and create a variable in it by calling request.getAttribute or session.getAttribute there. So the same variable can be used in other JSPs.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit object are nothing but a standard that says whenever a jsp is converted to a servlet, the sevlet will create some objects in the code, that your code can use. Thats it. To understand it more clearly, read some translated jsp file.

[see here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/285670/JSP/java/Creating-custom-implicit-object)

Comment: I understand that . Is there a way I can make this translator to create my user defined object.